# Dimensions of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, dimensions

In the following picture, I would like to use the same width for the rounded rectangles and the same height for the arrows (take a look at the last ones).

To do that I need to store the dimensions of the nodes used. Is there an easy way to do that?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, calc}

% Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585865/6880
\newcommand\test[2]{%
    #1 & {} = {} & #2 \\[8mm]
}

\newcommand\step[3]{
    \draw [->,shorten < = 1pt, shorten > = 1pt]
           let \p1 = ([xshift=-1mm]#2-1.south east) ,
               \p2 = ([yshift=1mm]#3-1.north) 
           in (\p1) -- (\x1,\y2) ;
    \draw [->,shorten < = 1pt, shorten > = 1pt]
           let \p1 = ([xshift=1mm]#2-3.south west) ,
               \p2 = ([yshift=1mm]#3-3.north) 
           in (\p1) -- (\x1,\y2) ;
    \node [draw, fill=white, rounded rectangle] at ([yshift=-5mm]#2-2){\tiny\kern1em$#1$\kern1em} ;
}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{r@{}c@{}l}
    \test{2x+3}{5x-4}
    \test{2x  }{5x-7}
    \test{-3x }{-7}
    \test{x   }{\dfrac73}
    \CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \step{-3}{1}{2}
        \step{-5x}{2}{3}
        \step{\div (-3)}{3}{4}
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{NiceArray}$

 \end{document}
```

Comment: For the width, you can fix it with a `tikzset` or directly right after your `\begin{tikzpicture}` declaration. Use something like `\tikzset{mynode/.style={minimum width=20pt,draw,fill=white,rounded rectangle}}` then draw your nodes with `\node[mynode]`. For the height, you would have to determine which cell of the matrix is wider first. It's a bit tricky, at least for me.

Comment: For the widths of the rounded rectangles, a simple solution would consist in  nesting their contents in an `\eqmakebox` command (`eqparbox` package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Update***

I thought about a different solution that solves the problem of the arrows' length and at the same time, allows a normal code for the equations.

[image]

**The code**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\action}[1]{%
  &= \tikz[baseline=-.5ex]{%
    \path[use as bounding box] (0, -3ex) rectangle ++(1pt, 6ex);
    \draw[->] (-3.5ex, 3ex) -- ++(0, -6ex);
    \draw[->] (.5ex, 3ex) -- ++(0, -6ex);
    \path (-1.5ex, 0)
    node[draw, rectangle, rounded corners, fill=WG, thin,
    inner sep=1ex, minimum width=11ex, scale=.7] {$#1$};
  }
}
\definecolor{WG}{RGB}{217, 221, 221}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  2x +3 &= 5x -4 \\
  \action{3} \\
  2x &= 5x -7 \\
  \action{-5x} \\
  -3x &= -7 \\
  \action{\div(-3)} \\
  x &= \frac{7}{3}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

***First solution***
I'm proposing a solution based on nodes (in TikZ).  It is true that the alignment of `=` is lost.  It might be retrieved by breaking the equations into pieces further, but I don't know if you are interested.  Eventually, you can transform it into a LaTeX command.

[image]

- The height of each wide node is fixed such that the fraction fits into it.
- The arrows have the same length since they connect nodes at equal distances.
- There is a parameter `\d` which controls the horizontal space between the arrows.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math} 
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{WG}{RGB}{217, 221, 221}
\tikzset{
  w/.style={minimum width=22ex, minimum height=6ex},
  n/.style={draw, rectangle, rounded corners,
    fill=white, thick,
    inner sep=1ex, minimum width=10ex, scale=.7},
  m/.style={->, shorten <=-3pt, shorten >=-2.75pt}
}
\tikzmath{
  real \d, \il, \ol, \ie, \oe;
  \d = 35;
  \ol = 270 -\d;  \il = 90 +\d;
  \oe = 270 +\d;  \ie = 90 -\d;
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1ex and 5ex,
  every node/.style={text=black}]
  \node[w] (Iw) {$2x +3 = 5x -4$};
  \node[below=of Iw, n] (In) {$-3$};
  \node[below=of In, w] (IIw) {$2x = 5x -7$};
  \node[below=of IIw, n] (IIn) {$-5x$};
  \node[below=of IIn, w] (IIIw) {$-3x = -7$};
  \node[below=of IIIw, n] (IIIn) {$\div(-3)$};
  \node[below=of IIIn, w] (IVw) {$x = \frac{7}{3}$};

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node[gray, fill=WG, fit=(Iw) (IVw), inner sep=0pt] {};
    \draw
    (Iw.\ol) edge[m] (IIw.\il)
    (Iw.\oe) edge[m] (IIw.\ie)
    (IIw.\ol) edge[m] (IIIw.\il)
    (IIw.\oe) edge[m] (IIIw.\ie)
    (IIIw.\ol) edge[m] (IVw.\il)
    (IIIw.\oe) edge[m] (IVw.\ie);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I will use it in another context.

Comment: I  understood from your comment that it wasn't the solution you were looking for.  I added a different one, based only on a new command for the transformations from an equation to the next.

Comment: Indeed I have another solution for the display above (this is similar to your new solution with `align*`). But I also need to draw "block diagrams of mathématical unctions". For this 2nd case, I will use your TikZ solution.